# How to disable toolbar in iframe?

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to deactivate this toolbar in iframe [image], I was looking in this page and I found this hint `#toolbar=0&navpanes=0`, however it doesnt work for the Safari browser. It works really good in Chrome.

Someone knows how to disable for all browsers? Or maybe a way to sort...

PD. I tried to use `document.getElementById('toolbar').style.display = "none";` and doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: i wanted to say document.getElementById("toolbarViewer"), sorry